# How can React Native send a "Bitmap" image (not filepath) to an Android module?

Tags: android, react-native, bridge

I have to use an Android module in React Native (through `React Native Bridge`) and one of its methods needs an image to print. The image is of `Bitmap` type (not a file path OR a file in the device).

This is the signature:
`void printLogo(Bitmap image, boolean isBuffer)`

Also, these are the insructions for the `Bitmap` image (I will have to abide with them from the React Native side:

`image –Image resource Bitmap object, the width must be less than 384 pixels and an integer multiple of 8, high pixel must be an integer multiple of 8`

Any ideas how this can be sent to the native module?

Thanks.